# modify a query of a joomla module

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

i have a module which executes two functions. the first filters and showsthe latest comments per category. the second one filters and shows the top commenters of all categories. i want to hack it in order to show the top commenters per category. for the first one there is in the backend the option to select category but for the top commenters there is not.

here is the code of the module. forgive me for its length.

```
class modK2CommentsHelper
{

public static function getLatestComments(&$params)
{

    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
    $limit = $params->get('comments_limit', '5');
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $aid = $user->get('aid');
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $cid = $params->get('category_id', NULL);

    $jnow = JFactory::getDate();
    $now = K2_JVERSION != '15' ? $jnow->toSql() : $jnow->toMySQL();
    $nullDate = $db->getNullDate();

    $model = K2Model::getInstance('Item', 'K2Model');

    $componentParams = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_k2');

    $query = "SELECT c.*, i.catid, i.title, i.alias, category.alias as catalias, category.name as categoryname
    FROM #__k2_comments as c
    LEFT JOIN #__k2_items as i ON i.id=c.itemID
    LEFT JOIN #__k2_categories as category ON category.id=i.catid
    WHERE i.published=1
    AND ( i.publish_up = ".$db->Quote($nullDate)." OR i.publish_up <= ".$db->Quote($now)." )
    AND ( i.publish_down = ".$db->Quote($nullDate)." OR i.publish_down >= ".$db->Quote($now)." )
    AND i.trash=0 ";
    if (K2_JVERSION != '15')
    {
        $query .= " AND i.access IN(".implode(',', $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels()).") ";
    }
    else
    {
        $query .= " AND i.access<={$aid} ";
    }
    $query .= " AND category.published=1 AND category.trash=0 ";
    if (K2_JVERSION != '15')
    {
        $query .= " AND category.access IN(".implode(',', $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels()).") ";
    }
    else
    {
        $query .= " AND category.access<={$aid} ";
    }
    $query .= " AND c.published=1 ";

    if ($params->get('catfilter'))
    {
        if (!is_null($cid))
        {
            if (is_array($cid))
            {
                JArrayHelper::toInteger($cid);
                $query .= " AND i.catid IN(".implode(',', $cid).")";
            }
            else
            {
                $query .= " AND i.catid=".(int)$cid;
            }
        }
    }

    if (K2_JVERSION != '15')
    {
        if ($mainframe->getLanguageFilter())
        {
            $languageTag = JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();
            $query .= " AND category.language IN (".$db->Quote($languageTag).", ".$db->Quote('*').") AND i.language IN (".$db->Quote($languageTag).", ".$db->Quote('*').")";
        }
    }

    $query .= " ORDER BY c.commentDate DESC ";

    $db->setQuery($query, 0, $limit);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $pattern = "@\b(https?://)?(([0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+:)?[0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+\@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'()-]+\.)*([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/[0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().;?:\@&=+$,%#-]+)*/?)@";

    if (count($rows))
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {

            if ($params->get('commentDateFormat') == 'relative')
            {
                $config = JFactory::getConfig();
                $now = new JDate();
                if (K2_JVERSION == '30')
                {
                    $tzoffset = new DateTimeZone(JFactory::getApplication()->getCfg('offset'));
                    $now->setTimezone($tzoffset);
                }
                else
                {
                    $tzoffset = $config->getValue('config.offset');
                    $now->setOffset($tzoffset);
                }

                $created = new JDate($row->commentDate);
                $diff = $now->toUnix() - $created->toUnix();
                $dayDiff = floor($diff / 86400);

                if ($dayDiff == 0)
                {
                    if ($diff < 5)
                    {
                        $row->commentDate = JText::_('K2_JUST_NOW');
                    }
                    elseif ($diff < 60)
                    {
                        $row->commentDate = $diff.' '.JText::_('K2_SECONDS_AGO');
                    }
                    elseif ($diff < 120)
                    {
                        $row->commentDate = JText::_('K2_1_MINUTE_AGO');
                    }
                    elseif ($diff < 3600)
                    {
                        $row->commentDate = floor($diff / 60).' '.JText::_('K2_MINUTES_AGO');
                    }
                    elseif ($diff < 7200)
                    {
                        $row->commentDate = JText::_('K2_1_HOUR_AGO');
                    }
                    elseif ($diff < 86400)
                    {
                        $row->commentDate = floor($diff / 3600).' '.JText::_('K2_HOURS_AGO');
                    }
                }
            }
            $row->commentText = K2HelperUtilities::wordLimit($row->commentText, $params->get('comments_word_limit'));
            $row->commentText = preg_replace($pattern, '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="\0">\0</a>', $row->commentText);
            $row->itemLink = urldecode(JRoute::_(K2HelperRoute::getItemRoute($row->itemID.':'.urlencode($row->alias), $row->catid.':'.urlencode($row->catalias))));
            $row->link = $row->itemLink."#comment{$row->id}";
            $row->catLink = urldecode(JRoute::_(K2HelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($row->catid.':'.urlencode($row->catalias))));

            if ($row->userID > 0)
            {
                $row->userLink = JRoute::_(K2HelperRoute::getUserRoute($row->userID));
                $getExistingUser = JFactory::getUser($row->userID);
                $row->userUsername = $getExistingUser->username;
            }
            else
            {
                $row->userUsername = $row->userName;
            }

            // Switch between commenter name and username
            if ($params->get('commenterName', 1) == 2)
                $row->userName = $row->userUsername;

            $row->userImage = '';

            if ($params->get('commentAvatar'))
            {
                $row->userImage = K2HelperUtilities::getAvatar($row->userID, $row->commentEmail, $componentParams->get('commenterImgWidth'));
            }

            $comments[] = $row;

        }

        return $comments;
    }

}

public static function getTopCommenters(&$params)
{

    JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'components'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'tables');
    $limit = $params->get('commenters_limit', '5');
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $aid = $user->get('aid');
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) as counter, userName, userID, commentEmail FROM #__k2_comments WHERE userID > 0 AND published = 1 GROUP BY userID ORDER BY counter DESC";
    $db->setQuery($query, 0, $limit);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $pattern = "@\b(https?://)?(([0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+:)?[0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+\@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'()-]+\.)*([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/[0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().;?:\@&=+$,%#-]+)*/?)@";

    $model = K2Model::getInstance('Item', 'K2Model');

    $componentParams = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_k2');

    if (count($rows))
    {

        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {

            if ($row->counter > 0)
            {
                $row->link = JRoute::_(K2HelperRoute::getUserRoute($row->userID));

                if ($params->get('commenterNameOrUsername', 1) == 2)
                {
                    $getExistingUser = JFactory::getUser($row->userID);
                    $row->userName = $getExistingUser->username;
                }

                if ($params->get('commentAvatar'))
                {
                    $row->userImage = K2HelperUtilities::getAvatar($row->userID, $row->commentEmail, $componentParams->get('commenterImgWidth'));
                }

                if ($params->get('commenterLatestComment'))
                {






                    $query = "SELECT * FROM #__k2_comments WHERE userID = ".(int)$row->userID." AND published = 1 ORDER BY commentDate DESC";

                    $db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);
                    $comment = $db->loadObject();

                    $item = JTable::getInstance('K2Item', 'Table');
                    $item->load($comment->itemID);

                    $category = JTable::getInstance('K2Category', 'Table');
                    $category->load($item->catid);

                    $row->latestCommentText = $comment->commentText;
                    $row->latestCommentText = preg_replace($pattern, '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="\0">\0</a>', $row->latestCommentText);
                    $row->latestCommentLink = urldecode(JRoute::_(K2HelperRoute::getItemRoute($item->id.':'.urlencode($item->alias), $item->catid.':'.urlencode($category->alias))))."#comment{$comment->id}";
                    $row->latestCommentDate = $comment->commentDate;
                }

                $commenters[] = $row;
            }
        }
        if (isset($commenters))
            return $commenters;
    }

}
```

}

every help is appreciated. thank you very much

Comment: Ok so we know what you want to do, now what have you tried?

Comment: my first thought was to change the query in the second function. but i think that is not possible because i need a parameter which will provide the category..in the first function there is from backend..